# Сортировка данных в цикле

Tags: циклы, php, сортировка

```
for($i = 0; $i <= @mysql_num_rows($query_agents); $i++) {
 $data_query_agents = mysql_fetch_array($query_agents);

 $agent_id = $data_query_agents['id'];
 $agent_rate_plus_q = $data_query_agents['agent_rate_plus'];
 $agent_rate_minus_q = $data_query_agents['agent_rate_minus'];
 $agent_rate_summ = ceil($agent_rate_plus_q/$agent_rate_minus_q);

 echo "ID: $agent_id | Рейтинг: $agent_rate_summ";
}
```

Вообщем как сделать сортировку в цикле по возрастанию, опираясь на $agent_rate_summ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К чему такое извращение? Почему нельзя выполнить сортировку прямо в запросе?

```
SELECT id, CEILING(agent_rate_plus/agent_rate_minus) as agent_rate_summ FROM имя_таблицы ORDER BY agent_rate_summ ASC
```

**UPDATE**
Костыль вполне может быть таким:

```
$a = array();
while($data_query_agents = mysql_fetch_array($query_agents)) {
   $agent_rate_plus_q = $data_query_agents['agent_rate_plus'];
   $agent_rate_minus_q = $data_query_agents['agent_rate_minus'];
   $a[$data_query_agents['id']] = ceil($agent_rate_plus_q/$agent_rate_minus_q);
}
asort($a);
foreach($a as $agent_id => $agent_rate_summ) {
  echo "ID: $agent_id | Рейтинг: $agent_rate_summ";
}
```

Comment: @Равнодушный, нужно именно извращение. Ваш способ мне не пригодится.

Comment: Добавил извращение. Будет работать при условии, что `id` - уникальны, а `agent_rate_minus` всегда не нуль.

Comment: @Равнодушный. В цикле foreach используется $agent_rate_summ, но в твоём коде, где цикл while, нет такой переменной. Ошибка?)

Comment: Эх... У меня отпал вопрос, зачем использовался `for` для обхода результата запроса. 

Никакой ошибки, читай ман по `foreach`.

Comment: @Равнодушный, $a as $agent_id => $agent_rate_summ. По Вашему коду эти переменные даже не заданы...

Comment: Обход ассоциативного (необязательно) массива:

`
foreach(массив as ключ => значение) {
 echo "ID: ключ | Рейтинг: значение";
}
`

Так очевиднее?

Comment: @Равнодушный, доперло. Спасибо!